# Magento 2: How to get first and last name of customer?

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-account, customer-attribute

I have a customer ID and I want to get first name and last name of that customer. Any solution?

Answer (score 9):

*The Best idea  to use **repository interface**  for getting customer data Magento 2.2.*.

```
Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface
```

Use function [***`getById($customerId)`***](http://devdocs.magento.com/codelinks/attributes.html#CustomerRepositoryInterface)

Inject that class on `__construct` function then use this class of getting customer object

> ```
> public function __construct(
> \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository 
> ){
>   $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
> }
> public function getCustomerDetails()
> {
>   $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);
>   if($customer->getId()){
>       echo $customer->getFirstname();
>       echo $customer->getLastname();
>
>   }
> }
> ```

**You want to use Object Manager then this**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerRepository = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface::class);
$customer = $customerRepository->getById({CUSTOMER_ID});
if($customer->getId()){
    echo $customer->getFirstname();
    echo $customer->getLastname();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use below code**

```
$customerID = 10; // your customer-id
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerObj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')
            ->load($customerID);
$customerFirstName = $customerObj->getFirstName();
$customerLastName = $customerObj->getLastName();
```

**By factory method:**

```
protected $_customers;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customers
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_customers = $customers;
    ...
}

public function getCustomer($customerId)
{
    //Get customer by customerID
    $customer = $this->_customers->load($customerId);
    echo $customer->getFirstName(); //Print Customer First Name
    echo $customer->getLastName(); //Print Customer Last Name
}

public function getCollection()
{
    //Get customer collection
    return $this->_customers->getCollection();
}
```

Note: It is not recommended to use objectManager directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve like this also:

```
   <?php  



namespace Mastering\Itdesire\Block\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    protected $_customer;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer,
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
    )
    {
        $this->_customer = $customer;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

     public function getCustomer()
    {
        $customerId = '189'; //You customer ID
        $customer = $this->_customer->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('eq' => $customerId));
        echo "Customer Name:".$customer->getFirstName();
        echo "Customer Name:".$customer->getLastName();
    }

}
```

Hope, This will help you some extend.